# Non thread-safe code using async and DataRow

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

When executing the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncDataRow
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Execute");

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    program.Execute();
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
            {
                foreach (var exception in aggregateException.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("AggregateException.InnerExceptions: " + exception.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception.Message: " + ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private void Execute()
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(i, i.ToString());
            }

            var taskList = new List<Task>();

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                taskList.Add(ChangeStringValue(dataRow));
            }

            Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        }

        private async Task ChangeStringValue(DataRow dataRow)
        {
            var id = (int)dataRow["ID"];

            var newValue = await Task.Run(() => CreateNewValue(id));

            dataRow["Name"] = newValue;
        }

        private string CreateNewValue(int id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - CreateNewValue", id));
            return id.ToString() + "New StringValue";
        }
    }
}
```

Intermittently a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown on this line of code

`dataRow["Name"] = newValue`

Exception message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

I'm trying to be more specific identifying the issue, but the closest I got was to simplify the code to reproduce the error.

I think it has something to do with the DataRow reference type being passed into the async method, but I would like to know why this code is not thread-safe.

Comment: As you seem to have found, `DataRow` elements cannot be mutated from multiple threads at the same time.  You'll need to not be manipulating them from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of thread-safe classes in .Net framework is very small and each would explicitly call out its safety (most are found in `System.Collecions.Concurrent` namespace). For all other types you need to provide your own thread safety mechanisms. DB related classes definitely fall into category of non-thread safe for write. Frequently classes explicitly allow multiple thread-safe reads.

In your case [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) can be *read* from multiple threads and you only need to synchronize writes:

> Thread Safety
>
> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

Standard approach for building a lot items - split items in ranges and generate each independently and then merge after all are done.

Partial sample based on original code, `MyRowResult` is class to hold all data for row that needs to be updated.

```
        var taskList = new List<Task<MyDataRow>();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            taskList.Add(ChangeStringValue(dataRow));
        }

        // await for proper async code, WaitAll is fin for console app.
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray());

        // back to single thread - safe to update rows
        foreach (var task  in taskList)
        {
            task.Result.DataRow["Name"] = task.Result.Name;
        }
    }

    private async Task<MyRowResult> ChangeStringValue(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        // on multiple threads - perform read only operations of rows
        // which is safe as explicitly called out in the documentation
        // "This type is safe for multithreaded read operations."
        var id = (int)dataRow["ID"];

        var newValue = await Task.Run(() => CreateNewValue(id));

        return new MyRowResult { Name = newValue, DataRow = dataRow };
    }
```

Notes:

- some classes (like UI controls) require even stricter thread safety- can be called on original thread only
- Helpers in `Parallel` class may simplify running code in parallel (like [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx)).